# I want delete a duplicate lines

Tags: jet

I have a big file (7 milion rows) where some of rows are repeated, I want delete a duplicate lines . For this reason, I used from:

```
sort {file-name} | uniq -u> data.txt
```

But I saw again in the new file, repeated data: for example:

```
14693 10167 184228271 184227954 184227954 2001 1 1 6 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 1 1700 0 0 0 -99
14694 10167 184228271 184227954 184227954 2001 1 1 6 0 0 52816 0 0.5 0 0 1 1700 41.91 1756.45 73612.74 -99
```

But 2 rows have different column , may be because of this subject?

Please help me about delete in repeate row in the my file.

Regards
Yahya

Comment: 14693 10167 184228271 184227954 184227954 2001 1 1 6 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 1 1700 0 0 0 99

Comment: 14694 10167 184228271 184227954 184227954 2001 1 1 6 0 0 52816 0 0.5 0 0 1 1700 41.91 1756.45 73612.74 -99